# DatePicker is not returning the correct date. Is it because NSDate defaults to absolute time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I saved a task's due date as 8:45 today. However the log shows the due date as

```
2013-04-26 01:45:46 +0000
```

What gives? Here's my code

```
#import "DatePickerViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "ListItemObject.h"

@class ListItemObject;

@interface DatePickerViewController ()


@end

@implementation DatePickerViewController

@synthesize dateLabel;
@synthesize pick;
@synthesize listFieldText;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pick.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    UIBarButtonItem *saveDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(saveList:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveDate;
    [pick addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(IBAction)saveList:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", pick.date);
    [ListItemObject saveListItem:[PFUser currentUser] withName:listFieldText withDate:pick.date];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(IBAction)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];

}
```

Do I need to do something similar as what I did with `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: What's wrong with the date it shows you?

Comment: Today is the 25th where I am and it was 8:45PM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date and time displayed represents the same time as the time you saved, but in GMT. This is because an `NSDate` represents a single point in time, with no information on formatting or adjusting that time for various time zones. Logging the `NSDate` returned by pick.date will display the time in generic GMT.

Using an `NSDateFormatter`, as you did in `updateDateLabel():`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];
```

will provide you with the time adjusted for your local time zone, which should then match 8:45.

Answer (score 1):

The `+0000` means you're seeing the date in the UTC time zone. `NSLog(@"%@", someDate)` will just return the `description` property from an `NSDate`. If you want the value to be adjusted to a particular time zone, you will need to set the `timeZone` property of an `NSDateFormatter`.